# Longest Ascending Sequence C#

Tags: c#

So I am quite new to C# and having face a problem which requires me to:

Search the longest ascending sequence of integers in an array of integers. As sequence of elements xi (1 ≤ i ≤ n) is ascending if xi < xi+1 for all i (1 ≤ i ≤ n - 1). The size of the array is to be chosen by the user. Values of the array are random numbers are between 0 and 1000 generated by the computer. The program shall print the start index and the length of the longest ascending sequence.

Here are my code so far (I can only sort array in ascending order):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace AscendingSequences
{
    class AscendingSequences
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ascending Sequence!");
            GenerateNumber();
        }

        public static void GenerateNumber()
        {
            int i, j, n, number;
            int[] array = new int[100];
            int[] array1 = new int[100];
            Random random = new Random();

            Console.Write("\nInput the number of element to be store in the array: ");
            n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("\nThe {0} array is generating-----\n", n);
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                array[i] = random.Next(1, 20);
                Console.Write("\nThe array|{0}| is {1} ", i, array[i]);
            }
            for(i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                for(j=i+1; j<n; j++)
                {
                    if(array[j] < array[i])
                    {
                        number = array[i];
                        array[i] = array[j];
                        array[j] = number;
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.Write("\nElements of array in sorted ascending order is: ");
            for(i=0; i<n;i++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} ", array[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the assignment given to me:
[image]

Comment: You haven't provided what is your issue?

Comment: Here you can get some tips -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `int[] arr = new[] { 3, 2, 1 }; int[] sorted = arr.OrderBy(n => n).ToArray();`

Comment: I'm quite new to this site too so I dont know 100% how to post a question correctly. My issue is that I dont know how to sort the array in ascending order like in the given example from my professor. Example:
Ascending Sequence:
Enter values: 
5
4
2
9
[15
3
5
[-1

The longest ascending sequence in 5 4 2 9 15 3 5 0 0 0 starts at index 2 and has a length of 3

Comment: Did my comment help you?

Comment: @fubo Maybe because sorting an array has been asked so many times, that it´s annoying to answer it again and again.

Comment: @fubo Because read HimBromBeere's comment 

Comment: @confused_unga_bunga So if I understand correctly: you don't want a sorted array but you want the index and length of the longest sequence of numbers that are already sorted(ascending) in a random array?

Comment: You are only generating 20 different number [array[i] = random.Next(1, 20);].  I think you are suppose to use 1 to 1000.  What happens if a number appears more than once?  Is 1,2,2,3,4.

Comment: @JoostK yes! that's what I meant :D

Comment: @jdweng I put there 20 because I want to test my code first before I put in 1000 number which is very very hard to see what happened

Comment: @jdweng it's ok to duplicate

Comment: @JohnyL in that a close / duplicate vote would be the right choice

Comment: Then is 1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3 an ascending sequence?

Comment: This question is however not a duplicate as far as I understand. The question is not about how to order a sequence but finding an ordered sequence

Comment: @jdweng uh huh, I guess so. I get this exercise from my professor. Even I who ask the question doesn't fully understand what my professor wants so I have to post the whole question + my progress so far so that someone could give me some enlightment :(

Comment: The problem here is that you have not tried anything to solve the problem. You have just ordered the array and according to your specs this should not be done. An hint. Start from the last element of the array and loop through the start. Check every number against the previous and count it if lesser or reset if you bigger one. Manage your startindex accordingly with the current position in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your approach to first order the array was wrong and that caused some people to be confused unfortunately.

if you start by ordering your array you lose the information of the original location of these elements which are important. Instead you should loop through your array and do a check if the current element is bigger than the previous one(ascending).

```
    //start and length are the "current" values and max are the max found
    int start = 0, length = 0, maxstart = 0, maxlength = 0;
    //loop through array (starting from index 1 to avoid out of bounds)
    for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        //check if current sequence is longer than previously recorded
        if (length > maxlength)
        {
            maxstart = start;
            maxlength = length;
        }

        //if previous element <= to current element
        if (array[i - 1] <= array[i])
        {
            //if the current element isn't part of the current sequence, then start a new sequence
            if (start + length < i)
            {
                start = i - 1;
                length = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                //count the length
                length++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is a .net fiddle with working code:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/1GLmEB

EDIT:
to reply to your question in the comments on how this works `start + length < i`

This condition checks if the current value is part of the sequence.
The variable `start` is the start of the last/current found sequence and `length` is the length.
When this condition returns true it means it falls outside the last found sequence and it resets the values of `start` and `length`(true = outside, false = inside)

So lets go through some cases and see why this works:

```
1 2 3 1 1 2 3 1 1
      * > > > e ^
start = 3 (*)
length = 4 (>)
i = 8 (^)
3+4 = e

3+4<8 //true : new sequence
```

so the last found sequence started at 3 and was 4 long.
this means that this sequence will end at index 7.
since we are currently checking for index 8 in our loop we can see that it **isn't** part of the same sequence.

```
1 2 3 1 1 2 3 4 1
      * > > > > ê
start = 3 (*)
length = 5 (>)
i = 8 (^)
3+4 = e

3+5<8 //false : current sequence
```

so the last found sequence started at 3 and was 5 long.
this means that this sequence will end at index 8.
since we are currently checking for index 8 in our loop we can see that it **is** part of the same sequence.

in hindsight it might have been less confusing if this if statement was turned around (true = inside, false = outside). However I won't change the code now to avoid further confusion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! I was totally confused by the given problem so I've make a wrong turn in the solution ^^

Comment: @Steve I know that you have good intention, thank you, but I've been very confusing in this question for 2 days. This isn't a homework but an  optional exercise for students to practice more on. I am not going to copy everything from the answer to my program. I'll try to understand it first before get my hand to work :)

Comment: @Steve, if one wants to learn, then she\he can learn a lot from a correct answer (let alone she\he would learn the existence of dotnetfiddle). If she\he is only after completing a homework, you cannot teach whatever you do.

Comment: @confused_unga_bunga if anything about my answer confuses you let me know, I'll try and explain it.

Comment: @JoostK nevermind, I am understand now. Thank you for your help so far!!

Comment: @JoostK Hi, can you explain me why do you write this condition please if (start + length < i)

Comment: I have manage to understand the first one but to this second condition I dont quite understand that. How is it working that cancel the previous sequences and start over the sequence again?

Comment: @confused_unga_bunga did this help?

Comment: @JoostK absolutely, thanks for the detail explanation. I was having a test yesterday so I reply quite late :(